# Does flatMap keep the order intact?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on a Spark application in which I have an `RDD[Array[Array[Float]]` and I'd like to convert it into an `RDD[Float]`. I'm having the following code to do this task for me:

```
val values = predictions.flatMap { x => (for(y <- 0 to x.length - 1) yield x(y)).map(c => c(0)) }
```

However I don't know whether the order of elements are changed after using `flatMap` or not? If so, is there any other solution that remain the order of elements intact?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto This is not true. Depending on order is typically not a good idea but flatMap doesn't shuffle the data.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto RDDs do have a fixed order despite being distributed.

Comment: So let'say my original rdd looks loke this : rdd([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]), after the applying my transformation I will get Rdd(1,2,3,4,5,6). Is that correct?

Comment: @zero323 thanks for the clarification! seems I got a wrong idea!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `flatMap` keeps the order intact. So do `map`, `filter`, etc.

Comment: So let'say my original rdd looks loke this : rdd([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]), after the applying my transformation I will get Rdd(1,2,3,4,5,6). Is that correct?

Comment: Not really. But I don't know if the situation should be included. Consider this [code snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jrOA5IUQRiatUe63DVbXfw). Since the `flatMap` is applied on a `Set`, there's no order to preserve.

Comment: @YanqiHuang The question is about `flatMap` on `RDD`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Oh. My bad. That was a blunder. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into the Spark source code.

```
def flatMap[U: ClassTag](f: T => TraversableOnce[U]): RDD[U] = withScope {
    val cleanF = sc.clean(f)
    new MapPartitionsRDD[U, T](this, (context, pid, iter) => iter.flatMap(cleanF))
}
```

and

```
private[spark] class MapPartitionsRDD[U: ClassTag, T: ClassTag](
    var prev: RDD[T],
    f: (TaskContext, Int, Iterator[T]) => Iterator[U],  // (TaskContext, partition index, iterator)
    preservesPartitioning: Boolean = false)
  extends RDD[U](prev) {

  override val partitioner = if (preservesPartitioning) firstParent[T].partitioner else None

  override def getPartitions: Array[Partition] = firstParent[T].partitions

  override def compute(split: Partition, context: TaskContext): Iterator[U] =
    f(context, split.index, firstParent[T].iterator(split, context))

  override def clearDependencies() {
    super.clearDependencies()
    prev = null
  }
}
```

The order of data should remain intact but some repartitioning may take place and this may or may not bother you (depending on what you are doing).