# Is it safe to use df.select(column_name).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect() when the order is important?

Tags: pyspark, rdd, flatmap, collect

As part of investigation I came to this link:

[flatMap doesn't preserve order when creating lists from pyspark dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619928/flatmap-doesnt-preserve-order-when-creating-lists-from-pyspark-dataframe-column)

which would suggest that it is not safe. However, these links state that flatMap() preserves order:

[Does flatMap keep the order intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004516/does-flatmap-keep-the-order-intact)

Does it mean that the function which does not preserve the order is collect() with respect to the `df.select(column_name).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()`?